# How to get query data using result from another query?

Tags: php, sql

i wanted to get the data from my second query using the first query result. But i cant What i wanted is to get id from the first query and get content using the id i got.

My 1st query

```
$query = "SELECT book_id , title, SUM(quantity) AS total_sales FROM  shopping_cart GROUP BY title ORDER BY total_sales DESC ";
```

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

```
                            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

2nd query

```
for ($rcount = 0; $rcount < count($row); $rcount++) {
                                $wanted_id = $result[$rcount]['book_id'];
                                $query1 = "SELECT * FROM books where id ='$wanted_id' ";
                                $result1 = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
                            }
```

i know theres somethign wrong with it but right now i cant seem to figure what how do i do it was wondering if im suppouse to use nested queries.

EDIT: heres my nested query

```
$query = "SELECT * from books where id IN (SELECT book_id AS id, title, SUM(quantity) AS total_sales FROM  shopping_cart GROUP BY title ORDER BY total_sales DESC )";
```

i got a "operand should contain 1 column error" tho

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$wanted_id = $row[$rcount]['book_id']`?

Comment: Also, I believe you need to use `UNION` for multiple selects.

Comment: im not combing 2 results, instead my first query where clause is suppose to get its conditions from the second query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need one query, join the books table to your shopping cart table to get the info about each book.

```
SELECT
  books.*,
  shopping_cart.book_id,
  shopping_cart.title,
  SUM(shopping_cart.quantity) AS total_sales
FROM
  shopping_cart
INNER JOIN
  books
ON
  shopping_cart.book_id = books.id
GROUP BY
  shopping_cart.title
ORDER BY
  total_sales DESC
```